# How to get profile data using AWS Cognito with Boto3 and OAuth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, boto3, amazon-cognito

Okay, so after a user logs in, I want to get their profile data. So the way I tried doing that was via boto3.client('cognito-idp').get_user but it keeps returning:

> NotAuthorizedException: An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the GetUser operation: Access Token does not have required scopes

To my knowledge, I have put every single built in Cognito scope and I am unsure why it is not working. Any help would be appreciated!

**My Auth Script**

```
scope = request.args.get(
    'scope',
    'email phone profile openid')
sumukey = make_session(scope=scope.split(' '))
authorization_url, state = sumukey.authorization_url(AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL)
session['oauth2_state'] = state
return redirect(authorization_url)
```

**My Return**

```
sumukey = make_session(state=session.get('oauth2_state'))
token = sumukey.fetch_token(
    TOKEN_URL,
    client_secret=OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
    authorization_response=request.url)
session['oauth2_token'] = token
return redirect(url_for('.index'))
```

**Current Attempt to get data**

```
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
response = client.get_user(
    AccessToken=session['oauth2_token']['access_token']
)
return str(jsonify(response))
```

**make_session**

```
return OAuth2Session(
    scope=scope,
    client_id=OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    token=token,
    state=state,
    redirect_uri=OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI,
    auto_refresh_kwargs={
        'client_id': OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
    auto_refresh_url=TOKEN_URL,
    token_updater=token_updater)
```